# Why does Samsung TV IR sensor ignore repeat codes?

Tags: arduino, samsung

Hey there trusty SO community,

I'm working on a project for my new Samsung "The Frame" TV using a IR remote controller. I am trying to send a "repeating" command (when a button is held continuously). I have no problem sending single commands, I am able to control almost everything I need at this point.

Unfortunately, sending the "power" code on the Samsung Frame TV simply selects the "art" mode. Using the original RF remote, the power button has the same action: "art" mode vs TV mode. In order to turn off the TV with the original RF remote, one has to hold down the power button for a second or two.

So I assume that the IR remote interface would be the same.

I have tried sending all sorts of commands (left arrow, right arrow, volume+, etc...) in repeat mode, but the TV only ever responds to the first command and ignores the "repeat" signals. To be clear, the repeat code blocks are being sent, but for some reason ignored. I was able to validate the repeats are sent correctly using a separate sender and receiver.

I have a working prototype of a custom remote that uses [this arduino library](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/src/IRReceive.hpp)

I have also read through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718588/understanding-ir-codes-for-samsung-tv) which is incredibly helpful in understanding the protocol.

I wasn't able to find exact information on the protocol of a repeat command, perhaps there is a bug in the library?

line of code that works for single commands:

```
IrSender.sendSamsung(0x0707, 0x02, 0); //address, command=pwr, number of repeats = 0
```

line of code that sends the repeat code

```
IrSender.sendSamsung(0x0707, 0x02, 10); //address, command=pwr, number of repeats = 10
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that version 3.7.1 and earlier of Arduino-IRremote library implements a "special" repeat handling message. After comparing the repeat protocol to a Samsung Brand remote control, it was found that the repeat messages are actually identical to the single message.

An update was made to [Arduino-IRremote](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote) in this [ticket](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote/issues/999) to fix the Samsung repeat messages.

A release has not yet been created as of typing this, but assume version 3.7.2 or greater will support Samsung correctly.